# Required field in custom component with template driven form does not mark the form as invalid

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am using `template driven form` in `angular 7`.

I created a custom component.

the custom component has `required` directive.

When the value is empty/null the `mat-error` appears correctly, but the parent form that contains it is not marked as invalid.

I have added a simple example to show this behavior
[custom component with required](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yw7soi?file=app%2Fradio-button-list.component.html)

Any idea?

Comment: where is the required directive? not on the stackblitz that you shared

Comment: sorry. its mistake, broken link , in work...

Comment: Now its correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After investigation, I understand that the `requierd` handling within the custom component take care of the display validation error,

In order to mark the form invalid in case of error, adding of `requierd` directive in the custom component using also needed.

```
<app-radio-button-list name="examinationTypeCtrl" 
                        [(ngModel)]="id"
                        #rd="ngModel"
                        required>
</app-radio-button-list>
```

[fixed example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yw7soi-vskvwy?file=app%2Fcustom-validator-example.component.html)

I found [this link](https://blog.angulartraining.com/tutorial-custom-form-controls-with-angular-22fc31c8c4cc),
Its perfect explanation about custom component with ControlValueAccessor implementation .